# Why this DATE_FORMAT used to convert a data format in this MySql query is not working?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into DB and I have the following problem with this query:

```
SELECT 
    count(*)                                                AS exist

FROM Market_Commodity_Price_Series                          AS MCPS
INNER JOIN MarketDetails_CommodityDetails                   AS MD_CD
      ON MCPS.market_commodity_details_id = MD_CD.id

INNER JOIN MarketDetails                                    AS MD
      ON MD_CD.market_details_id = MD.id

INNER JOIN CommodityDetails                                 AS CD
      ON MD_CD.commodity_details_id = CD.id

INNER JOIN CommodityName                                    AS CN
      ON CD.id = CN.commodity_details_id

WHERE 
     MD.market_name = "Butare"

AND CN.commodity_name = "Soya"

AND CN.language_id = 3
AND
     MCPS.price_date >= DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("03/15/2018", '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') 

AND 
     MCPS.price_date <= DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("03/15/2018", '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

The problem is that it returns always 0 as output.

I understood that the problem is related to these **WHERE** conditions:

```
AND
     MCPS.price_date >= DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("03/15/2018", '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') 

AND 
     MCPS.price_date <= DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("03/15/2018", '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

the problem is that the **price_date** field of my **Market_Commodity_Price_Series** table contains the value **15/03/2018** and not the **03/15/2018**.

This query is using:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("03/15/2018", '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

to convert from a date format to another but it seems that it is not working.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: "table contains the value 15/03/2018 and not the 03/15/2018." ... from few bad policies storing date as string, american is one of worst. Only yyyymmdd has (more or less) correct behaviour

Comment: not to mention you are comparing string to string with `>=` which *can* work but not always the way you expect.  Would be best to convert both dates to timestamp or use dates as mentioned above for comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) is a format which should match the date string that you pass in.

`'%d/%m/%Y'` implies the month should come second but since there isn't a 15th month in your case the month must be first, followed by the day.

`DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("03/15/2018", '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')` should fix it.

Comment: I am not completely sure I have understood the question you are asking. Does this fix the problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work as expected since you're now comparing two strings which are in different formats.  One in `'%Y-%m-%d'` and the column data in `%d/%m/%Y`

Comment: this project cannot be understood 'without vodka', like russian anecdote say

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know for sure since you haven't posted your table schema, but it appears you are storing `price_date` as a string and then attempting to compare it to a date.  Comparing strings this way *can* work but not always the way you expect. It would be preferable to either convert both dates to actual `date` format or use unix timestamp:

```
STR_TO_DATE(MCPS.price_date,'%d/%m/%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE('03/15/2018','%m/%d/%Y')
```

or

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(MCPS.price_date,'%d/%m/%Y')) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('03/15/2018','%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Both of those should work but the problem remains that you will be getting relatively poor performance this way and forget about using any kind of index.

A better approach would be to store your date in `date` format to begin with and consider using an index for performance sake.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to achieve what you are trying to do is just use date_format on the column itself. I am hoping that the values of the column are DateTime format.

so just do

```
DATE_FORMAT(MCPS.price_date,'%c-%d-%Y') >= STR_TO_DATE("03/15/2018", '%c-%d-%Y')      
   AND 
DATE_FORMAT(MCPS.price_date,'%c-%d-%Y') <=(STR_TO_DATE("03/15/2018", '%c-%d-%Y')
```